# Center Text with Image in MVC

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, view, display

I am trying to center the actionlink with the image but I am not being able to, could you try to see where did I fail.
In the code I display the the Images that are in the database

```
model List<Clothes>
@using FinalProject.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<br /><br /><br />

@if (Model != null)
{

        foreach (Clothes Id in Model)
        {

            if (Id.Amount > 0)
            {
                <div class="col-sm-3">

                    <img src="~/Content/img/@Html.DisplayFor(model => Id.ImagePath)" style="height:200px;width:200px;" />
                    <br />
                    <p class="navbar-text">@Html.ActionLink("Add To Cart", "Order", "RealCart", new { idOrder = Id.Id }, null)</p>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>            
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: try adding the class `text-center` to `.col-sm-3`

Comment: It did not work

Comment: just give us the rendered html and css. create a [mcve] of the problem described in your post. Your `c#` code is unnecessary since this is just a CSS issue.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I can see here, you defined:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
```

And if you want to display image in a center of a screen add `col-sm-12` istead od `col-sm-3` but before you try that, you might try adding a `text-center class` to `.col-sm-x` and some of this might help you. Please apply it and leave a reply here does it helped you.